# Error with missing module "events" on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, discord, discord.js

**bot in discord.js**

hello, i'm a newbie, i'm having this issue. i can't run my bot.

`Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'`

> My node is updated; 16.13

I just started now to use discord.js, because discord.py is dead and learn everything in a new place is hard *tear

Comment: Are you sure that it's 16.13? Try running `node -v` in the terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need node v16.6 for discord.js. This tells you how to upgrade [site](https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/update-node-js/).